# Things to remember while building a password manager

Tags: passwords, password-management

I want to build a simple password manager for desktop whose sole purpose is to store the passwords that can be read by the user as and when required.

I am not considering any fancy features such as autofill, cloud storage, password sharing etc.

Its purpose is to just store the passwords. What are the guidelines to build such secure password manager?

Comment: If you're actually planning to use this, then the best guideline is: don't. People who roll their own critical security software nearly always make mistakes that leave them vulnerable. Get yourself a reputable commercial or open-source password manager.

If you're just doing it as a programming exercise to learn about writing secure software then by all means go ahead.

Comment: Why should anything stop me from building a simple password manager? I understand the risks, that is why I am building a very basic one, which just stores the password.

Comment: @Curious: Because a password manager is never simple.

Comment: @Curious If you understand the risks, why do you need to ask for guidelines ?

Comment: Download and read about the ones that already exists, like [KeepPass](http://keepass.info/) or [Password Safe](http://passwordsafe.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks Joggen, @all everbody is behaving like I need PHD to build a basic version of password manager

Comment: @Curious Keepass is also open source, maybe download the source code and have a read to get an idea of the work required to build a basic password manager

Comment: There is no such thing as a "simple" or "basic" password manager. Unless it is broken, and worthless...

Comment: @AviD, A good reference to write a secure code will help

Comment: I got one here http://keepass.info/links.html#res

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Mike Scott's comment that it's best to use something which is already open-source which has gone through all the research and so on. If your doing the project for learning and personal usage then start off with basics such as:

- If you support clipboard don't forget to clear it during application been closed or after a set time period.
- Don't leave text in memory after it's usage
- Do good amount of research into encryption for your database and enforce a good password policy
- Support keyfiles for higher level of security
- Don't store any confidential information as plain text on disk
- Don't support any network related APIs or if you do make sure you validate all your buffers to avoid any remote buffer overflows.

You could go alot more into malware targeting your software using APIs such as FindWindow to read the strings out of your application and code injection using CreateRemoteThread but I'm not too sure of how complexity you want to secure the password from been stolen via malware.

I'd recommend you look into the code of an reputable password manager which is open-source as they will of done the above and more.

I know this list doesn't cover everything but I hope it's a good starting point for you.

Comment: Also required is in-memory protection, and don't forget about the component properties, and if this is in .NET or Java you have to worry about immutable strings, and and and...